# Django-viewflow how to get the current user?

Tags: django-viewflow

First day learning viewflow, I managed to get the tutorial to work, but I have a use case that I don't know how to implement.

What I want is when a workflow is started, I want it to automatically assign the task to the workflow starter (the user), how do I go about reference the current request object inside the workflow?

eg.

```
start = (flow.Start(CreateProcessView)).Permission(auto_create=True).Next(this.fill_request)
fill_request = (flow.View(UpdateProcessView).Assign(#current user))
```

Answer (score 1):

An `.Assign(...)` could be specified with a callable that takes a process activation and should return a user. Ex `.Assign(lambda act: User.objects.get(...))`

There are several callable shortcuts provided by Viewflow. Any `this.[task_name].owner` point to a user who completed that task, and `activation,process.created_by` points to a user who made the `.Start` task

```
fill_request = (
    flow.View(UpdateProcessView)
    .Assign(lambda act: act.process.created_by)
    # .Assign(this.start.owner)
 )
```